# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'project.routing'

Tags: python, django, django-channels, socketchannel

I have installed django channels and I have added routing.py in project root folder and added the line 
`ASGI_APPLICATION = 'project.routing.application'`
but whenever i tried to run the server 
i get

```
   raise ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module %r" % path)

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'scrapshut.routing'
```

downgrading channels version to 1.5 works but i want to figure out whats the issue with channels 2

```
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.1.0
autobahn==19.6.2
Automat==0.7.0
certifi==2019.6.16
cffi==1.12.3
channels==2.2.0
channels-redis==2.3.3
chardet==3.0.4
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.7
daphne==2.3.0

defusedxml==0.6.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.5
gunicorn==19.9.0
hiredis==1.0.0
hyperlink==19.0.0
idna==2.8
incremental==17.5.0
msgpack==0.6.1
msgpack-python==0.5.6
oauthlib==3.0.1
Pillow==6.0.0
psycopg2==2.8.3
pycparser==2.19
PyHamcrest==1.9.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
pypiwin32==223
python-decouple==3.1
python-social-auth==0.2.1
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2019.1
pywin32==224
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0
six==1.12.0
social-auth-app-django==3.1.0
social-auth-core==3.2.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
Twisted==19.2.1
txaio==18.8.1
urllib3==1.25.3
```

i just want the server to recognize the routing application and start working

EDIT(routing.py):

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter,URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from notifier.consumers import EchoConsumer



application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": URLRouter([
        path("ws/", EchoConsumer),
    ])
})
```

EDIT2: whenever i import routing application from the project folder

```
from project import routing
```

now im getting this error

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Comment: Can you import the module? E.g. if you add a line `import scrapshut.routing` in the settings module, does the line raise an error?

Comment: It seems like the problem is on your project architecture.

Comment: @hoefling there is an secret key error if i tried to import routing

Comment: So this is the real issue you should try to fix first. Once the module is importable, the error with asgi app string will resolve by itself.

Comment: @hoefling can you tell me how to fix that issue

Comment: Modify the question, adding the new exception you observe.

Comment: @hoefling the question has been updated please have a look

Comment: What does your `SECRET_KEY` setting look like? Is it `SECRET_KEY = ''`? The error message is pretty clear about what's wrong here.

Comment: SECRET_KEY = '-st5jfrgd!x5%r6t9z6danja$***********'

Comment: this is how it looks like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195430/discussion-between-mounikes-mintu-and-hoefling).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem which I've managed to solve.

1. First: locate your ***asgi.py*** file
2. Then: in your ***settings.py*** type the following:

`ASGI_APPLICATION = "NAME_OF_FOLDER_WHERE_ASGI.PY_FILE_IS_LOCATED.asgi.application"`

what you're doing in the ***settings.py*** file is referencing the location of the file, the actual file, and then the application variable inside that file.